# HTTP POST query how to calculate content length

Tags: java, http, post, http-headers, multipartform-data

I am making a HTTP POST query to a server and I am creating the post body manually.
I think I am making some mistake with the content-length header because on the server side when I get the http response at the beginning I see the headers with http response 200 and then when in my php script I print the post parameters and file names I get the correct values but together with some junk bytes.
Here is the body of my http post:

```
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
str.append("POST /tst/query.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        + "Host: myhost.com\r\n"
        + "User-Agent: sampleAgent\r\n"
        + "Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x\r\n" 
        + "Content-Length: 172\r\n\r\n"
        + "--AaB03x\r\n"
        + "content-disposition: form-data; name=\"asd\"\r\n\r\n123\r\n--AaB03x\r\n"
        + "content-disposition: form-data; name=\"pics\"; filename=\"file1.txt\"\r\n"
        + "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n555\r\n"
        + "--AaB03x--"
);
```

Here is the output from the server(ignore [0.0] - it comes from the console where I print the result)

```
[0.0] HTTP/1.1 200 OK

[0.0] Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2011 11:53:11 GMT

[0.0] Server: Apache

[0.0] Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[0.0] Content-Type: text/html

[0.0] 

[0.0] 6

[0.0] Array
[0.0] 

[0.0] 2

[0.0] (
[0.0] 

[0.0] 1

[0.0]  

[0.0] 1

[0.0]  

[0.0] 1

[0.0]  

[0.0] 1

[0.0]  

[0.0] 1

[0.0] [

[0.0] 3

[0.0] asd

[0.0] 5

[0.0] ] => 

3
123
1
2
)
0
```

And the php script on the server which is as simple as you can think of:

```
<?php 
    print_r($_POST) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String boundary = "AaB03x";
String body = "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
            + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"asd\"\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "123\r\n"
            + "--" + boundary + "\r\n"
            + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pics\"; filename=\"file1.txt\"\r\n"
            + "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "555\r\n"
            + "--" + boundary + "--";

StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
str.append("POST /tst/query.php HTTP/1.1\r\n"
         + "Host: myhost.com\r\n"
         + "User-Agent: sampleAgent\r\n"
         + "Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"\r\n" 
         + "Content-Length: " + body.length() + "\r\n"
         + "\r\n"
         + body
);
```

...I would say is the way it should be done

Comment: I tried and here is what I get:  response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 10 Dec 2011 11:53:11 GMT
Server: Apache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
6
Array
2
(
1
1
1
1
1
[
3
asd
5]
=> 
3
123
1
2
)
0

After each line there is \r\n but I removed it for readability. So if its not the content length why that happens? Is it ok the server to return all that bytes through the socket?

Comment: I think it is the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` that is messing you up, you need to "un-chunk" it - [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)

Comment: Please edit the question with a literal version of the output (in a code section) and the source of your PHP script

Comment: I updated the question. You are right about the chunking. Is there a way to tell the server to return it unchunked or it depends on server configuration and I have to parse it and un-chunk it manually?

Comment: I don't know of a way to control this from PHP, you would have to modify the server configuration. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538880/prevent-apache-from-chunking-gzipped-content) may help you find an acceptable solution to your problem.

Comment: Having said all this, I suspect you might do better to just use the [Apache provided HTTP related packages](http://hc.apache.org/) which will handle a lot of this stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is sufficient to solve my problem. I will talk to the guy who manages the server and we will decide what to do.

Answer (score 7):

From the HTTP RFC ([RFC2626, 14.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13))

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

In other words you should count the number of bytes (`octets`), therefor `\r\n` should be considered to be 2 octets/bytes.

Comment: OK so in that case the content-length is 181 i that query but the server still returns  something strange: int the php script I say print_r($_POST) and i get the params together with some byte here and there which make no sense :(

Comment: IMHO '\r\n' sequences count as one (1) octet, not two.  Please see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406022/how-is-a-multipart-content-length-value-calculated/31406023#31406023.

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed since this question was posted.  Many of the modern HTTP/REST frameworks and API's will automatically handle Content-Length and other calculations.

My experience is that the Content-Length must be byte-specific, and must be calculated at the time the request is being made, since the data will likely be dynamic and change between requests.

The headers can impact the body, so take that into account as well.  For instance, the Content-Type header will affect how the payload is encoded.  If the body is being sent `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the size of the body will be quite different then a request in which it is encoded and sent as `multipart/form-data`.

Aside from that, the calculation of the payload length should be fairly simple.  As Filip Roséen indicated, any line/control characters (\n \r) must also be included in the calculation.